How can I transfer only A records from one DNS zone to another without using scripts, full zone transfers?
I have two DNS servers for different zones:
subdomain.example.com (subdomain)
example.com (main domain)

The goal is to dynamically transfer A records from subdomain.example.com to example.com without using scripts, full zone transfers.
Here are the constraints and requirements:
The two servers have different SOA records and configurations.
I cannot use scripts, zone transfers (AXFR) for synchronization.
The A records need to be added automatically to the example.com zone without overwriting existing records.
Can anyone help with the configuration steps and advice on how to set this up? Ideally, I need to ensure:
Secure and authenticated updates between the servers.
Only the A records should be transferred.
No existing data in the example.com zone should be overwritten.

well, the authorative nameserver for example.com, how are you interacting with it? If you don't want to script it, why not do it in the web interface your domain hoster probably provides to you?

"I've set up both servers, and we are adding records to the subdomain via the frontend. The requirement is that whenever A records are added to the zone file of subdomain.example.com, they should automatically be reflected in the zone file of the example.com domain. This synchronization can be easily done when the SOA (Start of Authority) is the same by setting up primary and secondary DNS. However, in our case, the SOA records are different, so the standard primary-secondary setup won’t work."

but "automatically" means "scripted". And your requirement is "no scripting", so I'm not clear on how you're going to resolve this.

Actually we did this using script. Using dig we are getting all the records from subdomain and then by using script we are adding A records to the zone file of main domain. Problem is we cannot use script. Is it possible without script?

Like zone transfer happens between master and slave without any scripting
